# Using parameter[:user_id] ,params[:user_id], params["userid"] in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While studying a Rails application I saw statements like:

```
parameter[:user_id]
params[:user_id]
params["userid"]
```

Can anyone tell me if there any major difference between them? Or, are all
fetching parameters only and can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parameter[:user_id]
```

I don't think this is something official. However there's a `parameters` method on the current request object. See `request.parameters` in a controller action.

```
params[:user_id]
```

Using the `params[:user_id]` is the same as calling `request.parameters[:user_id]`. Also `params[:user_id]` is the same as `params["user_id"]`. See [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).

I am not sure if that's just a typo on your part, but `params[:user_id]` and `params["userid"]` are not the same, even with `HashWithIndifferentAccess`. The `_` won't just go away so they can hold different values.

Answer (score 0):

`params` and `parameters` are the same. They return both `GET` and `POST` parameters in a single hash.

There is no such a thing as `parameter`.

ref: [rails api](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

Comment: It might be a regular local hash.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to look at the context in which each one is used. `params` is the normal parameter hash made available to methods in your controllers. It contains the parameters passed in as part of the request as `GET` or `POST` params.

So, given the following URL:

```
http://www.testsite.org/some_resource?user_id=13
```

The `params[:user_id]` would contain the value `13`.

If the URL instead was:

```
http://www.testsite.org/some_resource?userid=13
```

You would need to use `params[:userid]` to get the value. So it all comes down to the way the URLs are made for the different controllers.

There's a third way, where you can map parts of the URL itself to params in the routes into your application. See `config/routes.rb` in your application. For instance with the following route:

```
match '/user/:user_id' => 'users#show'
```

You could pass in an URL like this:

```
http://www.testsite.org/user/13
```

And in your UsersController.show method you could access the user id by using `params[:user_id]` like normal.

The `parameter` hash is most likely a local copy of or reference to the params hash in a helper method or something.